# Heap sort "visual" tree prints extra zeros

Tags: c, diagram, heapsort

I've learned Heap Sort with a visual representation of it with the infamous tree diagram ([here](http://goo.gl/quHC1)), so I set out to find a way to print one out and I've progressed very well so far. My only problem seems to be that if, there aren't any more values to fill up on the line, my program seems to print zeros for some reason.

I'm certain it's probably an error in my code, or an extra line that needs to be added but I'm also looking for advice if this was the best approach. Code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int HeapArray[] = {165, 245, 398, 426, 575, 661, 775, 895, 901, 1028, 1184, 1283, 1350,1427, 1598, 1698};

int main()
{
    int i = 0, numL = 1;
    int j, k;

    for(k = 0; k < 6; k++)
    {
        if(HeapArray[i] == 0)
            break;

        for(j = 0; j < numL;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", HeapArray[i]);
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        numL *= 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Things to mention:

- In the other most for-loop, I've using the value 6 as the maximum lines to print, however the program stops printing on the line with the last array values in it.
- I haven't implemented any alignment to make the diagram 100% accurate since it seemed easy enough to leave for last (i.e. no extra code to confuse me).

Answer (score 1):

Your index i is probably going past the bound of the array

You have 16 elements, so the first time you print 1, then you print 2, then 3, etc

In total you would print 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 15 on the fourth line.

When you get to the last line (fifth line), you only have one element to print. However, your inner loop goes from 0 to 16, going past the bounds of the array (and so it prints 0s)

You should add a check in the inner loop to make sure you still have enough elements.

Note that I also highly recommend you actually add a 0 element to the end of the array, so you are not relying on memory outside of its bounds